# Rails set locals via before_action without using instance variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am still quite new to ruby & to rails and trying something - I am not sure if it is actually possible (or even useful):

I want to set variables in a before_action, but I dont want them to be instance variables, but later rendered in views via `render locals: {}`.

Controller

```
before_action :set_image_and_location, only: [:new, :my_method]

def new
  render locals: { image: image, location: location }
end

def my_method
  # do other stuff
  render locals: { image: image, location: location }
end

private

def set_image_and_location
  image = Image.find_or_initialize_by(params[:id])
  location = Location.find(image.location_id)
end
```

So how do I get them from the "set_image_and_location" to the methods without using instance variables? Or is this not possible or in general a bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have configured the ability to preset `locals` via the `before_action` hook by using a custom function for rendering (say `render_with_locals`) and an instance variable `@_locals` as a temporary storage:

```
before_action :set_common_locals

def new
  render_with_locals
end

def my_method
  render_with_locals
end

# You can replace any parameter or add some new parameters
def my_other_method
  render_with_locals locals: { image: image2, other_option: other_option }
end

private

def render_with_locals(*args)
  options = args.extract_options!
  locals = options[:locals] || {}
  options[:locals] = @_locals.merge(locals)
  render(*args, options)
end

def set_common_locals
  @_locals ||= {
    image: image,
    location: location,
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a gem, which I think might be suitable for your use case - decent_exposure.

```
expose(:image) do
  Image.find_or_initialize_by(params[:id])
end
expose(:location) do
  Location.find(image.location_id)
end
```

https://github.com/hashrocket/decent_exposure

Comment: Hey adam, thanks for your answer I am actually more interested in how I could do that myself - for the sake of learning and understanding :)